# How to hide custom-background on desktop (over 992px width)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image: Why is custom background showing?]

Why is custom background showing? Here is the css i have added that should work.

```
    @media (min-width: 992px) {

body.custom-background {
background-image: none !important;
display: none;   }
```

}

Link to the website: http://goo.gl/RgG2Ct (scroll down and you will se this strip that is only suppose to be on the mobile version)

Comment: We need to see the code - and not only the css. Try to delete the empty () too,

Comment: I dont know how to find the code, it's a wordpress-theme i am modifying and the creators wrote me body.custom-background is what refers to this background that is uploaded via the wordpress backend.

More accurately this is what i was told:

Hello,

You need to make the below changes to your style.css file to remove image in the theme. The file will be seen in wp-contents/themes/kane.

++++++
body.custom-background {
background-image: none !important;
}
++++++

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
```

Comment: That's media screen and, not media and screen ;)

Comment: Alright. Weird. Can you edit your original post with the original CSS you use to display the background please ?

Comment: Background is added via wordpress-theme backend. Not sure how to find that. I have added a link to website in question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) 
{
 body
       {
         background-image: none !important;
       }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: background: none !important . try this

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean things up a bit... try it like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
body.custom-background {
    background-image: none !important;
    display: none;
}}
```

It seems you have an extra set of () and one misplaced }